# looping position for SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, while-loop, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I thought I had a pretty firm understanding of while loops. I want the left_spinner to move from off the screen on the right to off the screen on the left.

Then move back to off screen on the right side and back to off the screen on the left. Code wise I don't see the problem.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var left_spinner = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        left_spinner = self.childNode(withName: "left_spinner") as! SKSpriteNode
        left_spinner.position = CGPoint(x: 675, y: 0)

        left_spinner.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -675, y: 0), duration: 3.0))

        goalLoop()
    }

    func goalLoop(){
        left_spinner.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -675, y: 0), duration: 3.0))

        while (left_spinner.position == CGPoint(x: -675, y: 0)){
            left_spinner.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 675, y: 0), duration: 0.0))
            left_spinner.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -675, y: 0), duration: 3.0))
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any synchronisation loop here, the SKAction API provide you ways to sequence actions. Just replace your whole code with :

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    left_spinner = self.childNode(withName: "left_spinner") as! SKSpriteNode
    left_spinner.position = CGPoint(x: 675, y: 0)

    // Prepare base actions
    let moveLeftAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -675, y: 0), duration: 3.0)
    let moveRightAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 675, y: 0), duration: 3.0)

    // Prepare sequencing
    let loopCount = 10
    let leftRightAction = SKAction.sequence([moveLeftAction, moveRightAction])
    let pingPongAction = SKAction.repeat(leftRightAction, count: loopCount)

    // Run final action
    left_spinner.run(pingPongAction)
}
```